# URLs set with lining figures regardless font settings

Tags: xetex, hyperref, urls

I’ve noticed during my XeLaTeX typesetting with `hyperref` package that since not so long ago, URLs (using `\url`) have been typed in lining figures (as opposed to the oldstyle figures) whatever my setting for default body font is.

I think that this was done for good reason to improve the readability of the URLs. Nevertheless, can this actually be easily changed if I want to have all figures in my text back to oldstyle, including those in the URLs?

Comment: Please provide a MWE which demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command '\urlstyle`.

Compile the following with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers={Monospaced,OldStyle}]{Minion Pro}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.89]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{/the/path/to/my/File123/890}

\urlstyle{rm}
\url{/the/path/to/my/File123/890}
\end{document}
```

You'll get:

[image]